# Problem with Flash and ExternalInterface on Windows

Tags: javascript, swfobject, settimeout, externalinterface

I'm using SWFObject 2.2 to embed three Flash movies on a page, then using JavaScript's SetTimeout to try to play and pause the movies with ExternalInterface. It's working in Firefox and Safari on OS X, but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer 8 on Windows. The SWFs embed fine, but don't respond to play or pause.

```
var params = {
    wmode: "transparent",
    bgcolor: "#000000"
};

var attributes1 = {};
attributes1.id = "movie01_swf";

var attributes2 = {};
attributes2.id = "movie02_swf";

var attributes3 = {};
attributes3.id = "movie03_swf";

swfobject.embedSWF("movie_one.swf","movie01_movie","650","275","10.0.0",null,null,params,attributes1,null);
swfobject.embedSWF("movie_two.swf","movie02_movie","650","275","10.0.0",null,null,params,attributes2,null);
swfobject.embedSWF("movie_three.swf","movie03_movie","650","275","10.0.0",null,null,params,attributes3,null);

function pause_movie01(){
    var movie01 = document.getElementById('movie01_swf');
    movie01.pause();
}

function play_movie02(){
    var movie02 = document.getElementById('movie02_swf');
    movie02.play();
}

function pause_movie02(){
    var movie02 = document.getElementById('movie02_swf');
    movie02.pause();
}

function play_movie03(){
    var movie03 = document.getElementById('movie03_swf');
    movie03.play();
}

setTimeout("play_movie02()",3000);
setTimeout("pause_movie01()",4500);
setTimeout("play_movie03()",6000);
setTimeout("pause_movie02()",9000);
```

I'm also using jQuery and easySlider to animate slides on the page; the movies are embedded on separate slides.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="movie"><div id="movie01_movie"></div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="movie"><div id="movie02_movie"></div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="movie"><div id="movie3_movie"></div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a Javascript error you don't see. Have you tried tracking JS errors with any tools like [Firebug for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)?

Comment: I get JavaSript errors:
play_movie02 is not a function
play_movie03 is not a function

Comment: Can you put a preview link with your html and js code where I could see what happens pls?

Comment: Hi dude, have you got any further with the problem?

Comment: No, we're scrapping it and going to an all-Flash solution. It's not my first choice but we have a deadline.